# How can I get a string between 2 asterisks?

Tags: java

So I was looking at reddit and was wondering how they managed to do the formatting thing with the bold and the italic via asterisks encapsulating text, so I tried replicating that effect in java. I tried a lot of things and the following code is a scramble/mix/mashup of everything I tried

```
  public static ArrayList<String> redditReformat(String message) {
    ArrayList<String> single = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> doubl = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> fin = new ArrayList<>();

    if (message.contains("*") && !message.contains("**")) {
        ArrayList<Integer> asterisks = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int index = message.indexOf("*"); index >= 0; index = message.indexOf("*", index + 1)) {
            asterisks.add(index);
        }

        HashMap<Integer, Integer> patterns = new HashMap<>();
        for (int start : asterisks) {
            for (int end : asterisks) {
                if (start < end) {
                    if ((start + 1) != end) {
                        if (!patterns.containsKey(start) && !patterns.containsValue(end)) {
                            single.add(message.substring(start, end));
                            patterns.put(start, end);
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (message.charAt(start + 1) == message.charAt(start)) {
                            if (message.charAt(end + 1) == message.charAt(end)) {

                                ArrayList<Integer> doubleasterisks = new ArrayList<>();

                                if (!patterns.containsKey(start) && !patterns.containsValue(end)) {
                                    doubl.add(message.substring(start + 2, end - 1));
                                    if (doubleasterisks.size() < 2) {
                                        doubleasterisks.add(start + end);
                                    } else {
                                        patterns.put(doubleasterisks.get(1), doubleasterisks.get(2));
                                        doubleasterisks.clear();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (String s : single) {
        fin.add(s);
    }
    for (String d : doubl) {
        fin.add(d);
    }
    return fin;
}
```

Yes it's messy and probably horrible, I've tried simple and complex things but this isn't going well. The method is supposed to return the asterisks between the a message as well, so like "haha *lol* potato" (stackoverflow formats the asterisks)

It currently returns "*lol" instead of "*lol*" and it just doesn't work when done with **

It also fails when there's more than one encapsulation.

Comment: Why don't you use regular expressions?  This would be easy if you did.

Comment: The **bold**  and _italic_ stuff is actually [Markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown)

Comment: They use a markdown library; you could too. Regex aren't always the best approach, btw, sometimes you need something more suitable for parsing and processing. If your goal is to just understand regex you may want to state that.

Comment: Oh, there weren't regexes at all, sorry.

Comment: The formatting style on Reddit (and SO!) is known as Markdown.  Markdown allows for the simple syntax to be converted to HTML.  There are MarkDown parsers available that you can use such as Markdown4j

Comment: @wonderb0lt I'm trying to replicate the effect in the minecraft chat :)

Comment: Guys, note the java tag. I'm specifically wanting to do this in a Minecraft chat as a plugin (with other stuff for fun).

I know it's markdown. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regular expression pattern to find occurrences:

```
String s = "blah *lol* blah";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\*([^\\*]*)\\*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Prints:

```
lol
```

If you haven't come across regular expressions before, I strongly recommend you learn about them. They are useful in lots of text-extraction / text-munging situations.

The expression:

```
\\*([^\\*]*)\\*
```

Breaks down as follows:

```
\\*      match an asterisk (it's escaped with a backslash
         because * is a meaningful character in a regular 
         expression. It has to be double escaped because
         backslash is a meaningful character in a Java
         string.

(        start a capturing group

[^\\*]*  match zero or more characters that are not asterisk

)        end the capturing group

\\*      match another asterisk
```

(Actually, regular expressions may not handle every case perfectly here, as they don't handle nesting, e.g. `*italic **bold***`, but are probably good enough. A "proper" solution would be to write some lexing/parsing code that takes each character at a time, and maintains state. For this situation you may even need backtracking, as it's not clear whether a `***` starts an italic or bold section until you have parsed further.)

If you want this functionality, there are [lots](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=markdown) of pre-written Markdown parsers.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** Updated to use Bukkit's `ChatColor` constants

As people in the comments are saying you should probably use regular expressions for this task.

<strike>Reading a bit about Minecraft chat formatting it seems that in order to make `text` bold you need to surround it like this: `§ltext§r`. For underline it is similar: `§ntext§r`. In order to include the special character in the Java code you can use the unicode `\u00a7`.</strike>

Here is some example code using regular expressions to replace single asterisks as underline and double asterisks as bold:

```
public static String applyFormatting(String message) {
  // BOLD: replace all occurrences of "**text**" with BOLD+"text"+RESET
  message = message.replaceAll("\\*\\*([^\\*]*)\\*\\*", ChatColor.BOLD + "$1" + ChatColor.RESET);
  // UNDERLINE: replace all occurrences of "*text*" with ITALIC+"text"+RESET
  message = message.replaceAll("\\*([^\\*]*)\\*", ChatColor.ITALIC + "$1" + ChatColor.RESET);
  return message;
}
```

This will not work with nested formatting like `**This *is* a test**` though.
It has not been tested with Minecraft.

Comment: Instead of the special characters, ChatColor.BOLD or ChatColor.ITALICS is there, Is this adaptable to replace * with italics and ** with bold in some way? I don't really know regex :/

Comment: thank you. Your method resets the color codes after reformatting, is there a short of conserving that color? It can be manually changed and you force reset it that way.

Perhaps make the method return an arraylist of all the encapsulated messages instead with the corresponding chat color?

Comment: @SaadArdati [aetheria](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1326913/aetheria)'s answer gives you a way of iterating over the encapsulated messages so you can use that for what you are talking about. Although I'm not too sure what the problem with using the reset is.